# For $0\leq a,b \leq \pi$ if $\cos a = -\cos b$ then $\sin a = \sin b$

Tags: trigonometry

Problem:

Is it it true that for $0\leq a,b \leq \pi$

if $\cos a = -\cos b$ then $\sin a = \sin b$.

Thoughts:
When I draw a picture it makes sense but I am unsure what identity to use to show this is true. Any hints appreciated.

What about this:

First squaring both sides yields
$\cos^2(a) = \cos^2(b)$, then $1-\sin^2(a) = 1 - \sin^2(b)$ implies $\sin(a) = \sin(b)$

Comment: What are you using as your definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$? For me they are defined by the well-known differential equations and the answer to your question is an easy consequence of those equations (by an argument that makes the argument from a picture rigorous).

Comment: @RobArthan do you mean the taylor series expansions?

Comment: I meant "what are you using as your axioms for working with $\sin$ and $\cos$?". I think you have just told me the answer. Ennar's answer to your question using trigonometric identities and one or two other properties is good, but you should bear in mind that you can make your pictorial reasoning completely rigorous, by a very simple analysis of the signs of the functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ and their derivatives in the interval $[0, \pi]$.

Comment: Note that proper notation is $\cos a$, not $cos a$. See my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good, but what you have doesn't imply that $\sin a = \sin b$, but $\sin a = \pm \sin b$. Luckily, we can easily remedy this:

$$\cos a=-\cos b\implies \sin^2a = 1-\cos^2a=1-\cos^2b = \sin^2b\implies |\sin a\,| = |\sin b\,|,$$

and since $\sin x\geq 0$ for $x\in[0,\pi]$, we have $$\sin a =|\sin a\,| = |\sin b\,| = \sin b.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(a) = -\cos(b) \Rightarrow \cos(a)=\cos(\pi-b)\Rightarrow a=2k\pi\pm (\pi-b)$

Since $0\leq a, b\leq \pi$, we can understand that the aforementioned inequality works only for $k=0$ and $+(\pi - b)$:

$\Rightarrow a = \pi - b \Rightarrow \sin(a) = \sin(b)$

---

I'm using the fact that when

$\sin(x) = \sin(a) \Rightarrow x = 2k\pi +a$ or $2k\pi + \pi - a$

$\cos(x) = \cos(a) \Rightarrow x = 2k\pi \pm a$

$\tan(x) = \tan(a) \Rightarrow x = k\pi + a$

Answer (score 1):

Note:
$$ \cos b = -\cos(\pi - b) = -\cos(\pi+b) $$

Thus
$$ \begin{align}
\cos a &= -\cos b, \quad (1)\\
\cos a &= \begin{cases}
 \cos(\pi +b) \\
 \cos(\pi -b)
\end{cases}\\
\implies a &= \begin{cases}
 \pi +b + 2n\pi \\
 \pi -b + 2n\pi
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
where $n= 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots.$

Imposing the condition $0 \le a,\, b \le \pi$ reduces the set of solutions above to just a single solution:

$$ a = \pi -b$$
Hence, it follows that
$$\sin a = \sin b.$$

Note: Don't square both sides of $(1)$ because doing so will introduce spurious solutions and, hence, requires an additional step to verify all solutions at the end.

Comment: @Soroush khoubyarian, My apology, I was writing the solution before yours, but was then interrupted. When I posted it, I found yours had been posted!